# Trying to highlight current page in Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, navigation, highlight, current-page

I'm trying to highlight a navbar section, and the articles I found didn't work.

What I want to do is highlight the navbar section I'm on, while changing pages, for example, while being on index.html (Home), with Home highlighted, and then go to news.html (News), with News highlighted.

I searched articles, and the ones I found didn't work for me.

Here's my html code:

```
    <nav>
            </div>
        </label>
        <script src="nav.js"></script>
        <label class="logo"><a href="index.html">JR-Koders</a></label>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="active text">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="nav.html" class="text">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="j-koders.html" class="text">J-Koder</a></li>
            <li><a href="r-koder.html" class="text">R-Koder</a></li>
            <li><a href="koders.html" class="text">Koders</a></li>
            <li><a href="search.html"><i class="fa fa-search text"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>



    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Hamburger
        var menu = document.getElementById("hamburger");
    
    
        menu.onclick = function(){
            menu.classList.toggle("openhamburger");
        }

        // End of this section

    </script>
```

Here's my css code:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: arial;
}

nav{

    background: black;
    color: #20C20E;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}

.text{
    color: #20C20E;
}
label.logo{
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 80px;
    padding: 0 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}


.our-logo{
    width: 70px;
}


a { color: inherit; } 

nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 7px 13px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

a.active,a:hover{
    background: #1b9bff;
    transition: .5s;
}

label.a:hover {
    background: #1b9bff;
    transition: 3s;
}
```

I also have code for my nav bar to be responsive, but I didn't included it in here, but I hope it will work the same

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this — either just with CSS or with things like PHP. You haven't indicated what you've tried, or which method you would prefer.

Comment: What about the [`:local-link` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:local-link)?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see any html element with Id "hamburger" and css class "openhamburger" in your code.

The part which you want to highlight should be given an Id name "hamburger" or provide an our  element with the ID "hamburger". (As you have mentioned menu = document.getElementById("hamburger") in your javascript portion of code)

And how you want to highlight should be written in css with the classname "openhamburger" (Since you have mentioned menu.classList.toggle("openhamburger") in your javascript code).
**I assume as if you want to highlight navbar while clicking hamburger icon**

For instance:
HTML:

```
<div onclick = "highlightNavbar()">☰</div>

<nav id= "hamburger" >
<!--some html code-->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
/* Style in such a way you want to highlight navbar */
.openhamburger{
position:relative;
top: 30px;
color: deeppink
background-color:grey;
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function highlightNavbar(){
var menu = document.getElementById("hamburger")
menu.classList.toggle("openhamburger");
    }
</script>
```

The above code is as per the Id name and class name given in your javascript.

Comment: Thanks, It worked! But something else bugged...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let els = document.querySelectorAll('li > a');
els.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    els.forEach(a => a.closest('li a').classList.remove('active'));
    e.target.closest('li a').classList.add('active');
  })
})
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: arial;
}

nav{

    background: black;
    color: #20C20E;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}

.text{
    color: #20C20E;
}
label.logo{
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 80px;
    padding: 0 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}


.our-logo{
    width: 70px;
}


a { color: inherit; } 

nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 7px 13px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

a.active,a:hover{
    background: #1b9bff;
    transition: .5s;
}

label.a:hover {
    background: #1b9bff;
    transition: 3s;
}
```

```html
    <nav>
        <script src="nav.js"></script>
        <label class="logo"><a href="index.html">JR-Koders</a></label>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="text active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="text">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="text">J-Koder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="text">R-Koder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="text">Koders</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search text"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Hi there, It worked great, but it was only working with # links. Is there a way to make it work when changing pages(for example : index.html to example.html)?